# How to avoid lint checks on public fields in library module?

Tags: java, android, jar, lint, aar

I'm developing an Android library and one of the models has a few public fields that I want users to have access to. The class and its fields are marked public. However, I get a lint warning saying "Access can be private".

Is there way for me to deal with this other than just plain ignoring it or using `@SuppressWarnings("WeakerAccess")`?

Comment: Note that it is considered bad design to have public fields in classes, especially if it's a library class. It ties you to keeping the fields forever after, preventing changes to internal implementation. Provide accessor methods for those fields instead.

Comment: Use setters and getters.

Comment: @AndyTurner accessors make sense, can't believe I blanked on that. However, now lint warns me "Method `getName()` is never used". Is there a way to deal with this without suppress warnings? Can I let Android Studio know it's a library I'm making so that it doesn't do these lint checks for public methods?

Comment: You could (should!) write unit tests for the method.

Comment: @AndyTurner pssh alright thanks! :) you should make this an answer instead of comment btw so I can mark this resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is telling you that you can make the fields private, that's because you aren't accessing the fields outside the class.

This indicates that you're not actually testing your class, as even accesses from a test class would count as access.

Write some tests! Users of the library will thank you for it.

Of course, if your tests are in the same package, you'll then be told that the fields can be default visibility.

The tests you should be writing are those testing your library from the user's perspective: they should be in a different package so that you don't accidentally test things (like package private fields and methods) which are inaccessible and thus irrelevant to the user. These tests also make great "example code" for your library's​ documentation (which you've written too, of course).

---

Additionally, it is bad design - especially in a library - to expose fields outside the package. You should provide accessor methods (getters and setters) in order to allow yourself the flexibility to change your internal implementation later without breaking existing users of your API.